# Reload Parent Window CRM Online Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a Parent entity "A" and child entity "B". I have a subgrid on the parent form to create children. When a child is created and saved, I want the Parent form to reload. I have tried the following in javascript but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function ReloadParentWindow() {
    var loc = window.opener.location;
    window.opener.location = loc;
    window.opener.location.reload();
    window.parent.loacation.reload();
    window.parent.opener.location.reload();
    window.location.assign(window.location.href);
    parent.location.reload();
    window.top.location.reload();
}
```

ALSO tried the following:

```
   function onLoad() {

        setTimeout("refresh();", 2500);

    }

    function refresh() {
alert"A");
        Xrm.Page.getControl("clients").addOnLoad(GridOnloadFunction);
    }

    var GridOnloadFunction = function () {
    alert("B");
        // Xrm.Page.data.refresh(true);
        var Id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
        Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("esi_timelog", Id);
        window.location.reload(true);

    };
```

I am using CRM 2016 online, google chrome. Please help.

Comment: I see you tried a lot already. Is that QuickCreate form Or a popup window? Where are you calling this ReloadParentWindow method?

Comment: Please show the code where you open the window

Comment: Also, you have a typo here `window.parent.loacation.reload();` - you've spelt `location` incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Add an event on the load of the grid in the onload of the parent form. The on load is triggered every time you add a record using the + button:

`Xrm.Page.getControl('yourgrid').addOnLoad(onLoadGrd);`

Then in the function, you can call a refresh of the parent form:

```
function onLoadGrd()
{
   Xrm.Page.data.refresh()
}
```

This is the supported way.

Comment: function onLoad() {

    setTimeout("refresh();", 2500);

}

function refresh() {
    Xrm.Page.getControl("clients").addOnLoad(GridOnloadFunction);
}

var GridOnloadFunction = function () {

    // Xrm.Page.data.refresh(true);
    var Id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("esi_timelog", Id);
    window.location.reload(true);

};

Comment: Yes, I have alerts put in place.

Comment: Does alert("B") triggers too?

Comment: Yes, when I add a child record, save and close the form. I get "B" alert on screen. But the page doesn't get refreshed. I know because I have rollup field on the form. The rollup value doens't change.

Comment: A rollup field is only calculated every 12 hours. Here's how to trigger it more often https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/246436.

Comment: I am using the Dynamics 365 Workflow Tools which has step to calculate roolup field which can be used in workflows directly. But it still takes a few minutes to calculate. So the change is not instantaneous. I have to reload the form for it to show me the actual value.

Comment: Can't you make a sync workflow at the creation of your child entity?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var recordcount = null;
    function onLoad() {

    CheckRecordCount();
}

function CheckRecordCount() {
    try {
        setInterval(function () {
            if (Xrm.Page != null && Xrm.Page != undefined && Xrm.Page.getControl("myGrid") != null &&
                Xrm.Page.getControl("myGrid") != undefined) {
                var rowcount = Xrm.Page.getControl("myGrid").getGrid().getTotalRecordCount();
                if (recordcount == null) {
                    recordcount = rowcount;
                } else if (recordcount != rowcount)
                    Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName(), Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId());
            }
        }, 5000);
    } catch (ex) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(functionName + "Error: " + (ex.message || ex.description));
    }
}
```